# Display Brightness not working in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: brightness, hybrid-graphics

I upgraded to 12.04 using the synaptic package manager upgrade feature...

I have googled this problem and there is a lot of help available but none of a recent date and I never had this problem with Ubuntu 11.10 etc...

I have a HP pavilion g6 1302TX laptop with the AMD 7470M HD graphics card. I have (re)installed the AMD flgrx additional graphics drivers etc. No fix:

The gnome display applet reads "Cannot get laptop panel brightness" and the Fn + F7/F8 buttons no longer work My screen is very dim - almost unreadable.

I know variations on this question have been asked by many users, but all posts seem quite old and not related to my problem. Any ideas? Thanks for any help.